# Use SystemJS-builder to bundle Angular 2 Ahead-of-Time Compiler files

Tags: angular, deployment, module, compilation, systemjs

I've compiled my `Angular 2` app written in `typescript 2` using the *Ahead-of-Time compilation* instructions on [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile).

**main.ts**

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Now I have a lot of `ngfactory.ts` files as well as `.js` files. To tree-shake and bundle, I'm using the simple [systemjs-builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) task below:

```
gulp.task('demo-bundle', function() {
    var builder = new SystemBuilder();

    builder.loadConfig('./systemjs.config.js')
        .then(function(){
            return builder.buildStatic('dev/main.js', 'dist/bundle.js', {
                encodeNames:false,
                mangle: false,
                rollup: true
            });
        })
});
```

The bundling completes without errors, but the app fails in the browser with error:

> Error: No provider for NgZone!

If I change from Ahead-of-time to Just-in-time compilation by bootstrapping with:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Then the bundling and the app work as intended.

Any ideas on how to properly bundle the AoT compilation with `buildStatic`? (In tsconfig, `module` is `es2015` but I've also tried `system` and `commonjs`)

`@angular/compiler-cli 0.6.3`, `systemjs-builder 0.15.31`, `systemjs 0.19.39`

Comment: Hi @BeetleJuice, could you please share more about how you get the bundling to work? On my side I get the follwoing error: `Error on fetch for node_modules/@angular/core/index.js/src/linker/ng_module_factory.js`. Compiling with tsc everything works.

Comment: @jthe I'm now using the `[angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed)` project as the building and bundling tool for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent ages tracking this down - loading the umd bundles for the angular modules causes this error. Change to loading the index.js file in their folder instead.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to share that. The whole time I thought the problem was with ZoneJS.

Comment: Were you able to get treeshaking/rollup to work with systemjs-builder?  The cookbook rollup example doesn't seem to work because you need the builder to resolve packages.